# Restar una string

Tags: c++, string

Estoy realizando un proyecto para la universidad que involucra *object oriented programming*. Debo crear objetos (con valor `string`) y sumarlos, restarlos y multiplicarlos. Mi problema es en la resta. Se supone que debo iterar entre cada elemento del `string` ingresado en B y, si encuentro que ese elemento tiene coincidencia con algún elemento del `string` A, eliminarlo. En resumen regresar las letras que no se repiten entre ambas strings.

Este es el código que llevo hasta ahora, pero al ejecutarlo me regresa un *blank space*.

```
FunnyString operator - (FunnyString anotherMin)
{
    FunnyString finalWord;
    for (int i=0;i<(anotherMin.word).length();i++)
        for (int j=0;j<word.length();j++)
            if (anotherMin.word[i]==word[j])
            {
                (anotherMin.word).erase((anotherMin.word).begin() + i);
            }
            else
            {
              finalWord.word+=word[j];
            }
return finalWord;
}
```

¿Me podrían echar una mano? Por cierto ya hice overloading de símbolo + por ende no hay problema al construir los objetos como strings. Es solo en el código de la resta.

Aquí introduzco la clase FunnyString completa:

```
     class FunnyString
{
public:
string word;
FunnyString()
{};
FunnyString (char x[])
{
    word=x;
}
FunnyString operator + (FunnyString anotherPlus)
{
    FunnyString finalWord;
    if ((word[word.length()-1])==(anotherPlus.word[0]))
    {
        word.erase(word.begin() + word.length()-1);
        (anotherPlus.word).erase((anotherPlus.word).begin());
        finalWord.word= word + anotherPlus.word;
    }
    else
    {
        finalWord.word= word + anotherPlus.word;
    }
    return finalWord;
}
FunnyString operator - (FunnyString anotherMin)
{
    FunnyString finalWord;
    for (int i=0;i<(anotherMin.word).length();i++)
        for (int j=0;j<word.length();j++)
            if (anotherMin.word[i]==word[j])
            {
                (anotherMin.word).erase((anotherMin.word).begin() + i);
            }
            else
            {
              finalWord.word+=word[j];
            }
return finalWord;
}

};
```

Comment: Usas la clase `FunnyString`, cuya implementación desconocemos... ¿Cómo vamos a saber dónde se encuentra el error si nos falta la inmensa mayoría del código?

Comment: Listo. Disculpa por cierto.

Comment: No hay nada que disculpar. Los comentarios son para concretar detalles que no están claros en la pregunta. Nadie te va a exigir que hagas una pregunta perfecta a la primera... si le faltan cosas ya nos encargamos de decírtelo... aunque cuanto mejor lo hagas de primeras más atención recibirás :)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Pues bien, si pruebo el código con "abcd" y "b" (por ejemplo) el resultado es correcto... ¿no será que el error se encuentra en cómo manipulas la cadena resultante (es decir, fuera del operador de resta)?

Answer (score 1):

> Iterar entre cada elemento del `string` ingresado en B y, si encuentro que ese elemento tiene coincidencia con algún elemento del `string` A, eliminarlo.

No has establecido qué debe pasar si se intenta restar una cadena larga a una corta o si la operación debe ser [conmutativa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conmutatividad), así que te haré la propuesta más cómoda de implementar usando la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) y sus utilidades [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) y [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

#### Propuesta.

A nivel de pseudocódigo los pasos a seguir serían:

1. Identificar la cadena más corta y más larga.
2. Recorrer la cadena larga carácter a carácter

   1. Copiar, a una cadena nueva, los caracteres que no estén en la cadena corta.

Una posible implementación podría parecerse a:

```
std::string resta(const std::string &a, const std::string &b)
{
    std::string result;
    // Identificar la cadena más corta y más larga.
    const std::string &largo = a.size() < b.size() ? b : a;
    const std::string &corto = a.size() < b.size() ? a : b;

    // El resultado será, como mucho, tan largo como la cadena corta.
    result.reserve(corto.size());
    // Copiamos el contenido de 'largo' que cumpla la lambda
    std::copy_if(largo.begin(), largo.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [&corto](const std::string::value_type &c)
    {
        // Verdadero sólo si 'corto' no contiene 'c'.
        return std::find(corto.begin(), corto.end(), c) == corto.end();
    });

    return result;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WaLHgdeiZPYhiycq)</kbd>.

También podrías diseñar el algoritmo al revés si copias la cadena larga en `result` y borras las letras que estén en la cadena larga, para ello te sería útil [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).